# Grails: Create my datasource from a webservice

Tags: web-services, grails, datasource

I've read a lot about switching between multiple datasource on runtime, but as far as I understand they're already defined datasources. I'm not quite sure on how can I just asign the datasources properties on runtime from a webservice call.

I don't need to switch between datasources, just need to create only one datasource with conection data coming from a webservice.
Is there a way to retrieve these parameters from the webservice and create the datasource from that?

The policy here is to retrieve the datasource parameters from a webservice for all the projects, that way the connection data is not inside a file nor into the code, and is only manipulated by DBAs from a global security aplication.

I tried to call the web service in the same datasource file, but it didn't work.

Info:
Web service is a Soap 
Web service
Grails: 1.3.9

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can create a [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) that take care of calling your webservice and changing the settings of your dataSource.

Probably you will need to [delay the session factory creation](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1565), making sure Grails won't try to use your dataSource before you have all setted up correctly.

The BeanPostProcessor will looks like:

```
class WebserviceDataSourceBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        return bean
    }

    Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {

        if (bean instanceof DataSource){
           def info = //call webservice here...
           bean.username = info.username
           bean.password = info.password
           bean.url = info.url
           //checkout more setters in: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html
        }

        return bean
    }
}
```

And make sure you declared this Spring Bean in **resources.groovy**

```
beans = {
    webserviceDataSourceBeanPostProcessor(WebserviceDataSourceBeanPostProcessor)
}
```

If you will have more than one project with this same config comming from a webservice you may think in the possibility of a plugin for this, reusing your code.

Comment: He wants the app to be a `producer` of the webservice so that DBAs can `consume` it and send him the payload with the required info about datasource and eventually set it in config.

Comment: Ohhhh. I think you are correct. I misunderstood the question. App has to call a common webservice to get the credentials and database information. Yes, BeanPostProcessor is the way to go.

Comment: @dmahapatro the OP says: "I'm not quite sure on how can I just asign the datasources properties on runtime from a webservice call". I'm assuming that the connection properties returned from the webservice can change at any time and he wants to pick this up and configure his datasource, and not set this in config.groovy, since he says "runtime".

Comment: Correct you are. There are two aspects to the question and I think I got confused with that. When OP says "data coming from a webservice call", I apprehended it as data sent to the app as part of request payload from DBAs. I then realized DBAs would be unaware of what applications are running in company, and it his not DBAs responsibility to update the datasource of the application. I opened my eyes then and woke up from bed, ended my dream. :-D

Comment: Thanks to you all, sorry for the misunderstanding, in fact I only need one datasource that has to be created with data that I can not know, because it comes from a magical place called SecuritySystem through a webservice that I don't control (I just call it), and it is administrated by the DBA elves.
I'm testing your solution as soon as I get rid of some other task first and I let you know.
Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry about the newbie question but I just learned about beanPostProcessors. In what location of my Grails project should I place the WebserviceDataSourceBeanPostProcessor class?

Comment: Since it's just a Groovy class, you can put this in `src/groovy`.

Comment: Nevermind, but it threw this error:

[main] ERROR spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator  - [RuntimeConfiguration] Unable to load beans from resources.groovy
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: WebserviceDataSourceBeanPostProcessor for class: resources

Comment: Sorry again, I got it compiling, but from where and how should I call this BeanPostProcesor?

Comment: Checkout the link that I put in BeanPostProcessor. "ApplicationContexts can autodetect BeanPostProcessor beans in their bean definitions and apply them to any beans subsequently created"

Comment: Thanks, Sergio, It did work. Two remarks: I had to change the bean properties in the BeforeInitialization, not in the after, and I had to find a bean with beanName == "dataSourceUnproxied".